# Generating distributions with very small values with generative adverserial networks

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, generative-models, gan

I am using a GAN to generate a vector distribution. However, most of the values of this distribution are very close to zero, i.e $1 \times 10^{-7}$. The distribution also have minus values.

With these very small values, the GAN is having trouble to approximate the original distribution, since it is difficult for the GAN to tell the difference between very small values. But these small differences are crucial in my distribution.

There are a couple of values which are around $0.5$. Therefore, normalizing the data range to be between $[0,1]$ does not really work.

I think what I need is something like histogram equalization,but it should be invertible, since I need to obtain the original distribution at the end. Another way I can think of is an invertible function, which can push the values closer to zero to larger values, and does not affect too much to the already larger values.

I would be much grateful if someone can suggest me a function like this, or guide me on an alternative path on how to approach this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: log transform ?

Comment: It has negative values? Are they always small? Maybe $\widetilde{x}_k = \log(1+x_k)$? Or (more robust) perhaps $\widetilde{x}_k = \log(1 + x_k - m)$ where $m=\min_k x_k$?